# Safe variable length return in C

Tags: c, polynomials

I want to make a function that returns the roots of a polynomial, as part of a basic exercise. Is there a safe way to return a variable number of elements (0, 1 or 2, in this case), i.e. making sure the receiver knows how many items were returned so they can avoid a segfault ?

This is arguably more a question of API design than pure programming, the roots themselves are trivial but getting them there safely puzzles me.

Comment: You could return a `struct { T* ptr; size_t len; }`, by `malloc`ing the pointer inside the function and then asking the user to `free` it later. Or pass a `T* ptr` to the function and tell the user that it must be able to hold at least N elements, and returning a `size_t` with the number of elements you wrote. More generically, giving the user a pointer + length is a good approach to variable length data

Comment: @FilipeRodrigues I like the "pointers as input, length as output" idea, it works like `scanf` which everyone knows. Thank you.

Comment: Think about `fread( )`... Caller passes in a buffer, the size of each element and an element count to fill the buffer to full. Return is the # of elements loaded into that buffer... There are lots of _paradigms_ drifting around.

Comment: On a more general case, you can pass the function a callback, which will be invoked everytime a solution is found. Overkill in this case, but this way also has valuable pros (no memory allocation for example).

Comment: Unless these items are huge, you could simply have the caller allocate 3 items, then fill in as many as were used and return the size to the caller. Or wrap them all in a single struct, also caller-allocated. Anyway, to avoid this getting all broad and fuzzy, you should probably post some example code of what you have currently.

Comment: If the caller knows the degree of the polynomial, the caller could just supply a pointer to a buffer with room for that many roots.

Comment: @Lundin The purpose of the question was to be broad. My example may be constrained but I wanted to know how such a thing is done in general, and I think I got exactly what I asked for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case of a polynomial is special, as the caller knows how many roots there are at maximum. So the caller knows how much memory is needed to safely store the return value.

In this case it is easiest to let the caller pass a buffer to your function and store the roots in there. Your roots function would then only return the number of roots it found.

The other case (where the function returns freshly allocated memory) is way more complicated, and should be avoided if possible. You would introduce strong dependencies to your function (memory allocator) and this way fix the memory allocation schema. This is quite restraining (and unnecessary for your and perhaps many other use-cases). [1]

This could work:

```
int roots( double roots_out[], double coefs_in[], int ord)
```

This would be better (less error prone, even if one demands roots_out must have ord-1 elements)

```
int roots( double roots_out[], int nroots_max, double coefs_in[], int ord)
```

`ord` is the order of the polynomial (not the degree) and indicates how many elements there are in `coefs_in`

Note that there are still some questions left:

- What to return if there are infinitely many roots? (zero polynomial?)
- What to do if the buffer is too small? (Your solver may generate duplicate roots due to numerical inaccuracies. In other words `nroots_max = ord-1` may be sae from mathematical point of view, but not numerically)

[1]: Also even if you may think this way one would save some memory as the number of roots may be less than the degree, this comes with a caveat. During root calculation one needs a big buffer anyway as the number of roots is not known beforehand. So memory saving is a two step process anyway, and, in my opinion, this task should be delegated to the caller. This is most efficient I guess.

Comment: Perhaps `complex` and `const`? `int roots( complex double roots_out[], const double coefs_in[], int ord)`?

Comment: @chux  Yes it was off by one (thanks). Complex is one option, but I would make it a different function, as there may be different algorithms under the hood.

Comment: I suggest using `int roots(int ord,  double roots_out[restrict static ord], double coefs_in[restrict static ord])`. The `static` in the size expression informs the compiler that at least `ord` elements pointer by `roots_out` and `coefs_in` are valid. It can enhance optimization and provide better static analysis. `restrict` will tell the compiler that the pointer don't alias allowing generation of a better code.

Comment: I think you have answered my question perfectly. Thank you very much !